# Как принудительно вызвать деструктор в С++?

Tags: c++

Как принудительно вызвать деструктор в С++?

Comment: Подобный принудительный вызов — пример плохого дизайна.

Comment: Это не всегда так.
Бывают ситуации, когда требуется уничтожить объект, без освобождения занимаемой им памяти. После чего применить размещающий оператор new, что позволит сэкономить на операциях выделения и удаления памяти.

Comment: 99,9% такая оптимизация - неоправданное усложнение кода, котое повышает опасность возникновения ошибок, тогда как выигрыш в скорости окажется незаметен. Так что надо избегать такой оптимизации до последнего. Кроме того, раз уж так хочется переиспользовать объект, так может и не уничтожать его вовсе? Очень сомнительна необходимость в подобной оптимизации.

Comment: Классический пример: реализация оператора присвоения для объекта, содержащего ссылку.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Например, так:

```
PtrClass * ptr = new PtrClass();
ptr->~PtrClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

> После чего применить размещающий оператор new, что позволит сэкономить на операциях
> выделения и удаления памяти.

Это делается диспетчером памяти, путем перегрузки new/delete.

Answer (score 0):

Если есть желание принудительно вызвать деструктор, попробуйте сделать редизайн кода.

Answer (score -1):

Можно создать метод класса который бы вызывал delete this;

```
class test
{
public:
    int delet()
    {
        printf("delet!!!!");

        delete this;
        return 0;
    }
    test(){printf("test\n");}
private:
    ~test() {printf("\n~test!!!!");}
};

int main()
{
    test* a=new test;
    a->delet();
}
```

---

кому не нравиться оператор delete можно поступить так

```
  class test
    {
    public:

        test(){printf("test\n");}
        test* operator()()
        {
            return this;
        }

        ~test() {printf("\n~test!!!!");}
    };
    int main()
    {
        test a;
        a()->~test();

    }
```

Comment: delete еще и память удаляет. А если память под объект выделялась не с помощью new?

И если уж деструктор надо вызвать самому, то лучше сделать это правильно. Как было показано первом ответе.

Comment: можно просто и a.~test(). Только в вашем 2ром варианте деструктор будет вызван два раза. Думаю сами знаете чем это плохо.

Comment: если объект у нас будет создаваться в единственном экземпляре то это легко поправимо, иначе пусть пользователь создает еще одно поле, и вообще зачем пользователю так извращаться      
 ~test() {
  static int i=0;
  if(i)
   return;
  i++;
  printf("\n~test!!!!");}
    };